# How to group pandas dataframe and calculate statistical summary (mean and standard deviation) without current row value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe `df` with two columns `foo,bar`:

```
foo = [1,2,1,3,1,2,2]
bar = [10,11,9,10,11,15,13]
pd.DataFrame()
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(foo,bar)), columns =['foo', 'bar'])
```

Input df:

```
foo bar
 1  10
 2  11
 1  9
 3  10
 1  11
 2  15
 2  13
```

I need to get mean and standard deviation of `bar` for grouped (by `foo`) data but tricky part is I don't want to include the current row value into calculation.

Desired Output is something like following:

```
foo bar group_val_except_current_row group_mean_expect_current_row group_sd_except_curr_row
 1  10         [9, 11]                         10                            1.41
 2  11         [15, 13]                        14                            1.41
 1  9          [10, 11]                        10.5                          0.71
 3  10         []                              Null                          Null
 1  11         [10, 10]                        11                             0
 2  15         [11, 13]                        12                            1.41
 2  13         [11, 15]                        13                            2.82
```

I tried following code to get `group_val_except_current_row` column but using `set` eliminates repetitions.

```
dfa = df.groupby('foo').agg(lambda x: x.tolist()).reset_index()
dfa['group_values_list'] = dfa['bar']
del dfa['bar']
dfnew = df.merge(dfa)

dfnew['group_values_list'] = dfnew['group_values_list'].apply(set)
dfnew['bar'] = dfnew['bar'].apply(lambda x: [x]).apply(set)
dfnew['group_val_except_current_row'] = dfa['group_val'] - dfnew['bar']
```

and I am stuck, here.

``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution with set is possible, if 100% sure not duplicates per groups in `bar` columns is possible use `set`s similar like your solution with `np.mean` and `np.std` of lists with `if-else` for set `NaN` for empty lists (avoiding `Warning`):

```
df['group_val_except_current_row'] = df['foo'].map(df.groupby('foo')['bar'].apply(set)) - df['bar'].apply(lambda x: {x})

df['group_mean_expect_current_row'] = df['group_val_except_current_row'].apply(lambda x: np.mean(list(x)) if len(list(x)) > 0 else np.nan)
df['group_sd_except_curr_row'] = df['group_val_except_current_row'].apply(lambda x: np.std(list(x), ddof=1) if len(list(x)) > 0 else np.nan)
print (df)
   foo  bar group_val_except_current_row  group_mean_expect_current_row  \
0    1   10                      {9, 11}                           10.0   
1    2   11                     {13, 15}                           14.0   
2    1    9                     {10, 11}                           10.5   
3    3   10                           {}                            NaN   
4    1   11                      {9, 10}                            9.5   
5    2   15                     {11, 13}                           12.0   
6    2   13                     {11, 15}                           13.0   

   group_sd_except_curr_row  
0                  1.414214  
1                  1.414214  
2                  0.707107  
3                       NaN  
4                  0.707107  
5                  1.414214  
6                  2.828427
```

Another solution, if possible duplicates is exclude currect value in row in lists by indices - use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for currect indices for exclude and remove it in list comprehension:

```
s = df['foo'].map(df.groupby('foo')['bar'].apply(lambda x: list(x)))
counter = df.groupby('foo').cumcount()

df['group_val_except_current_row'] = [[j for i, j in enumerate(x) if i != c] 
                                         for x, c in zip(s, counter)]

df['group_mean_expect_current_row'] = df['group_val_except_current_row'].apply(lambda x: np.mean(x) if len(x) > 0 else np.nan)
df['group_sd_except_curr_row'] = df['group_val_except_current_row'].apply(lambda x: np.std(x, ddof=1) if len(x) > 0 else np.nan)
print (df)
   foo  bar group_val_except_current_row  group_mean_expect_current_row  \
0    1   10                      [9, 11]                           10.0   
1    2   11                     [15, 13]                           14.0   
2    1    9                     [10, 11]                           10.5   
3    3   10                           []                            NaN   
4    1   11                      [10, 9]                            9.5   
5    2   15                     [11, 13]                           12.0   
6    2   13                     [11, 15]                           13.0   

   group_sd_except_curr_row  
0                  1.414214  
1                  1.414214  
2                  0.707107  
3                       NaN  
4                  0.707107  
5                  1.414214  
6                  2.828427
```